# Do pdfs of Logistic and Student's t-distributions intersect only 2 times?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have 2 probability density functions of Logistic distribution with the same mean, but different variances, do they intersect only 2 times? Is it also true for Student's t-distribution?